# how to change boolean cutter to wireframe automatically?

Tags: modifiers

When add boolean modifier (difference/cut), how to make the 'cutter' object to be wireframe automatically so i can see the the result and the cutter/brush interactively.

Comment: You might be interested in the [booltool addon](https://www.blendernation.com/2014/05/14/add-on-booltool/)

Comment: Yes i used that addon, the problem is rather than display the cutter as wireframe, it will display as bounding box. This is not what i want. i want boolean op like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQfwyAU6X40&t=206s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the 'use wire instead of Bbox' in addon preferences.

Ctrl + Alt + U  to bring up this 'user preferences' window (just in case)

[image]